# Android tile based game

Tags: java, android

I develop tile based game to draw i use function `canvas.drawBitmap()` in each frame function drawBitmap using 400+ times when i use scroll (Gestures) performance is pretty bad.

Can anyone give me advice how to increase performance to make smooth animation.

```
public class DiamondIsometric implements Render{
    private int MapWidth;
    private int MapHeight;
    private Bitmap _surface;
    private Bitmap tempBitmap; 
    public DiamondIsometric(int MapWidth,int MapHeight,Bitmap _surface)
    {
        this.MapWidth=MapWidth;
        this.MapHeight=MapHeight;
        this._surface = _surface;
    }
    public MapObject[][] BuildMap()
    {
        int rx;
        int ry;
        MapObject[][] MapObjects = new MapObject[MapWidth][MapHeight];
        for(int x=0;x<MapHeight;x++)
            for(int y=0;y<MapWidth;y++)
            {
                rx=(x-y)*_surface.getWidth()/2;
                ry=(x+y)*_surface.getHeight()/2;
                MapObject temp = new MapObject(new Point(rx,ry),_surface);              
                MapObjects[x][y]=temp;              
            }
        return MapObjects;      
    }

    @Override
    public void Render(Canvas canvas) {     
    }
    @Override
    public void Render(Canvas canvas,MapObject[][] MapObjects)
    {
        Paint temp = new Paint();
        temp.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        canvas.drawPaint(temp);
        Bitmap toDraw = Bitmap.createBitmap(MapWidth*_surface.getWidth(), MapHeight*_surface.getHeight(), Config.RGB_565);
        int bitmapOffsetX,bitmapOffsetY;
        canvas.drawBitmap(this.Render2(canvas,MapObjects),0,0,null);

    }
    public Bitmap Render2(Canvas canvas, MapObject[][] MapObjects)
    {
        Paint temp = new Paint();
        temp.setColor(Color.BLACK); 
        tempBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(), Config.RGB_565);
        Canvas wideBMPCanvas = new Canvas(tempBitmap);
        int bitmapOffsetX,bitmapOffsetY;
        for(int i=0;i<MapObjects.length;i++)
            for(int j=0;j<MapObjects[i].length;j++)
            {
                bitmapOffsetX=(IsometricView.globalAnchor.x % MapObjects[i][j]._bitmap.getWidth());
                bitmapOffsetY=(IsometricView.globalAnchor.y % MapObjects[i][j]._bitmap.getHeight());
                wideBMPCanvas.drawBitmap(MapObjects[i][j]._bitmap,MapObjects[i][j].coords.x-IsometricView.globalAnchor.x ,MapObjects[i][j].coords.y-IsometricView.globalAnchor.y , null);

            }
        return tempBitmap;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a game engine like [andEngine](http://www.andengine.org/) or [libgdx](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/). They use OpenGL rendering which is usually much faster.

Update: If you want not to use OpenGL/game engines you should try to combine tiles into a larger bitmap. Create a larger bitmap and create a new canvas (new Canvas(largeBitmap)) to draw the tile to it. Drawing one larger is faster than drawing multiple smaller ones. For my Game [K'UMPA](https://market.android.com/details?id=de.greenrobot.kumpa) I used a similar approach, which is more complex in detail, because only a small part of the map is visible on the screen.

Comment: Updated the answer, in case you want to stick to software rendering using drawBitmap.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try to not create a bitmap at each render call.
I assume that you're calling render for each frame:

```
    public class DiamondIsometric implements Render {
    private int MapWidth;
    private int MapHeight;
    private Bitmap _surface;
    private Bitmap toDraw;
    private Canvas wideBMPCanvas;

    public DiamondIsometric(int MapWidth,int MapHeight,Bitmap _surface)
    {
        this.MapWidth = MapWidth;
        this.MapHeight = MapHeight;
        this._surface = _surface;

        this.toDraw = null;
        this.wideBMPCanvas = null;
    }
    public MapObject[][] BuildMap()
    {
        int rx;
        int ry;
        MapObject[][] MapObjects = new MapObject[MapWidth][MapHeight];
        for(int x=0;x<MapHeight;x++)
            for(int y=0;y<MapWidth;y++)
            {
                rx=(x-y)*_surface.getWidth()/2;
                ry=(x+y)*_surface.getHeight()/2;
                MapObject temp = new MapObject(new Point(rx,ry),_surface);              
                MapObjects[x][y]=temp;              
            }
        return MapObjects;      
    }

    @Override
    public void Render(Canvas canvas) { }

    @Override
    public void Render(Canvas canvas,MapObject[][] MapObjects)
    {
        Paint temp = new Paint();
        temp.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        canvas.drawPaint(temp);

        if (this.toDraw == null) {
            this.toDraw = Bitmap.createBitmap(MapWidth*_surface.getWidth(), MapHeight*_surface.getHeight(), Config.RGB_565);
        }
        if (this.wideBMPCanvas == null) {
            this.wideBMPCanvas = new Canvas(this.toDraw);
        }
        int bitmapOffsetX,bitmapOffsetY;
        for (int i = 0; i < MapObjects.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < MapObjects[i].length; j++)
            {
                bitmapOffsetX = (IsometricView.globalAnchor.x % MapObjects[i][j]._bitmap.getWidth());
                bitmapOffsetY = (IsometricView.globalAnchor.y % MapObjects[i][j]._bitmap.getHeight());
                this.wideBMPCanvas.drawBitmap(MapObjects[i][j]._bitmap, MapObjects[i][j].coords.x - IsometricView.globalAnchor.x,
                                              MapObjects[i][j].coords.y - IsometricView.globalAnchor.y, null);
            }
        }
        canvas.drawBitmap(this.toDraw, 0, 0, null);
    }
}
```